# Decoding a binary-like object back to the original string

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using python and mongodb.
I have the following string example:

```
hash = 'Z0pQ5dJos8Lz8USN/5P955P7228eW1BDPieuX+AgqvI='
```

I want to wrap it into BinData type in mongo, so I do the following:

```
self.db.test.insert({"ticket": Binary(base64.b64decode(hash.encode('ascii')), 0)})
```

Now, it saves it in mongodb as I intended:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("64f0a2392a9cc5cc98bc0b11"),
  "ticket": BinData(0, "Z0pQ5dJos8Lz8USN/5P955P7228eW1BDPieuX+AgqvI=")
}
```

However, when I retrieve it back in the python script, I can't seem to find a method that can decode it back to the original string it was, which is just "Z0pQ5dJos8Lz8USN/5P955P7228eW1BDPieuX+AgqvI=". I need it for comparison of things.

```
data = self.db.test.find()
```

The 'ticket' part in data looks like the following:

```
b"gJP\xe1\xd2h\xb3\xc2\xf3\xf1D\x8d\xff\x93\xfd\xe7\x93\xfb\xdbo\x1e[PC>'\xae_\xe0 \xaa\xf2"
```

I tried to use base64.b64decode but it doesn't give me the output I want. Also tried with decode("utf-8").

Any insight on how to do it?

Thanks

EDIT:
I actually tried now:

```
str(Binary(base64.b64encode(data.get("ticket"))))
```

It results in:

```
b'Z0pQ5dJos8Lz8USN/5P955P7228eW1BDPieuX+AgqvI='
```

How do I get rid of this b without using str trim "manually" and all of that?

Comment: Pretty sure you want `base64.b64encode`. `base64.b64encode(b"gJP ...")` -> `b'Z0pQ4dJos8Lz8USN/5P955P7228eW1BDPieuX+AgqvI='`

Comment: Thanks! I just did it, but do u know how to get rid of the b and get it as a clear string? without trimming

Comment: `base64.b64encode(b"gJP ...").decode()` -> `'Z0pQ4dJos8Lz8USN/5P955P7228eW1BDPieuX+AgqvI='`